# Does "The belief is that the earth is round" exemplify apposition?

Tags: grammar

> The belief is that the earth is round.

Do 'the belief' and 'that earth is round' correctly show apposition here?

Comment: No: the two phrases have the copular verb **be** between them.

Comment: Following CowperKettle's comment: if you remove "is" then you do have apposition:  *{The belief}, {that the earth is round}, is supported by visual evidence of photographs taken from outer space.*

Comment: The OP has posted a series of questions quite apparently (when examined together) seeking examples of apposition. I am marking most of them as duplicates. This might be retained because there is an existing answer and the OP's objective is relatively easily decipherable.

Answer (score 3):

No: the two phrases have the copular verb **be** between them. You can reformulate your sentence as

> It is generally believed that the Earth is round.

Compare:

> My sister, a nurse, is 28. ("My sister" and "a nurse" are in apposition)
>   My sister **is** a nurse. ("My sister" and "a nurse" are not in apposition)

Phrases that are in apposition play a similar role in the sentence. You can delete "my sister" and "a nurse" will work in its stead:

> A nurse is 28.

You cannot delete either "The belief" or "that the Earth is round" from your sentence and let the other phrase work in the stead of the deleted one.

Answer (score 3):

No.

But look at this:

> Long ago, many people thought that the earth was flat. In the classical period of Greek history, this view was replaced with a new belief. **The belief, that the earth is round, is now held by nearly all people.**

This sentence correctly shows *the belief* and *that the earth is round* set in apposition.

Comment: You pulled the noun clause out of his sentence and placed it in anohter sentence where it is no longer a subject complement (predicate nominative) but now serves the purpose of being an appositive. Clever.